# when is `new` required in Vala

Tags: vala

I was wondering the difference between

```
DateTime t = new DateTime.now_local();
```

and

```
File f = File.new_for_path(...);
```

Why does the former require `new` while the latter emits error with `new`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new` keyword can only be used with classes that define a constructor.

Only concrete class may define constructors. It's optional for GObjects as they can always be instantiated with `GLib.Object.new`.

In this specific case, `GLib.File` is defined as an abstract class and the `File.new_for_path` behave more like a factory that will select the implementation based on the protocol (i.e. `file://`, `ssh://`, ...) and return its corresponding instance.

The `GLib.DateTime` class does not inherit from `GLib.Object` and thus require an explicit constructor to be instantiated.

For structs, `new` can be used although it will emit a warning.